# How to compare the performance of 2 statistical samplers?

Tags: statistics, distribution, sampling

Say I have an orchard of 10 trees with a total of 1000 apples. Each tree in the orchard may have a different number of apples, or no apples at all. I have two bucket samplers: the first one is small, taking X% of the apples from a single tree at a time (i.e. per sample), and the second sampler is large, taking X% of the apples from two trees at a time. The X% of both samplers is identical, the sampling is without replacement (meaning that apples taken during in a specific sample remain out), and both samplers must make exactly 50 samples. Also, I'm assuming that the two samplers do not operate on the same orchard but each one of them has its own orchard, identical to the other one.

What I need is to compare the total amount of apples that each sampler yields after 50 samples. Naturally, if X=100%, both samplers will yield all the apples in the orchard and their performance will be the same; but how do I calculate the difference in their performance as a function of X% ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a solution for you, but I suspect there is some lack of information or I misunderstand something. I will describe the problems below using X=100 as example.

N=10 is the total population size of trees
BS1 collects X% apples from 50 trees
BS2 collects X% apples from 100 trees
Let i denote the i'the tree for i=1,..,10. And let yi denote the number of apples on tree i. Lets assume each tree has a fixed unknown amount of apples. Ofcause you say there is 1000 apples in total meaning when all apples from 9 of the trees are sampled we know the number of apples on the 10th tree - but I will ignore this, and assume yi is completely unknown.

If X=100% and we sample once
BS1 collect pick a random? tree to collect from with some probability - lets say 1/10 for each tree. At the same time BS2 does the same for two trees. Assuming BS2 and BS1 cannot pick the same tree, and BS1 always pick first.

After the first sample, BS1 has picked yi apples and BS2 has picked yl+yj apples, for (i,j,l in 1,...10, and i \ne j\ne l).

After the third sample only one tree will be left with apples.
Since BS1 pick first and we sample without replacement, BS1 will pick 3+1 trees and BS2 will pick 6 trees Thus BS1 will always pick more then half of the trees (since he pick first). The number of apples picked will then be the depending on how the apples are distributed on the trees.

Comment: So sorry, I left out some info: (1) I'm assuming that the two samplers do not operate on the same orchard but each one of them has its own orchard, identical to the other one. (2) Each sampler must sample his orchard 50 times, even if it samples a tree which it already sampled before.

Comment: That leaves a new question, since you must sample 50 times, you cannot have a sample without replacement as mentioned above. In a field of 10 trees both samplers will run out of trees after 10 samples. In the case of X=100

Comment: @user9446044 If you omitted essential info you need to edit your question and correct that omission.

Comment: I edited the original question. @Kirsten, thanks so much for your input!